# Stack overflow response API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm sending a POST request to my WebApi Asp.Net Core 3.0 and receiving an error Stack overflow.
Why this?

**My terminal response:**

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2 POST https://localhost:5001/clients application/json 5
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint 'Cardapio.Controllers.ClientsController.Post (Cardapio)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Route matched with {action = "Post", controller = "Clients"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Post(Cardapio.Models.Client) on controller Cardapio.Controllers.ClientsController (Cardapio).
Stack overflow.
```

**My controller:**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Cardapio.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Cardapio.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("clients")]
    public class ClientsController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("")]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Client model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);

            return Ok("Success");
        }
    }
}
```

**My client model:**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Cardapio.Models
{
    public class Client
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Ip { get; set; }

        public string Identification { get; set; }

        public string Secrets { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedAt { get { return this.CreatedAt; } set { this.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now; } }
    }
}
```

It's a simple controller, in the other with database access with entity framework don't have problems.

Comment: What does `Client` look like? Does it by any chance reference itself?

Comment: Client it's my model entity.

Comment: Yes, and what does that look like?

Comment: I've edit the question. Thanks!

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint to the method and single-step through the execution?

Comment: @citronas I just tested it, but it's fast, so once the request comes back, the error returns me.

Comment: Can you show what is the request you are sending ?

Comment: Oh yes, but the problem was solved. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your model is the issue, `CreatedAt` is referencing itself which will cause an endless loop of trying to retrieve or set the value.

A backing field is required when implementing logic behind getters & setters.

Here is an example which uses a backing field.

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Cardapio.Models
{
    public class Client
    {
        private DateTime createdAt;

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Ip { get; set; }

        public string Identification { get; set; }

        public string Secrets { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedAt { get { return this.createdAt; } set { this.createdAt = DateTime.Now; } }
    }
}
```

You can minimise this however by assigning a default value to `CreatedAt` as there's nothing particularly custom happening in the `get` or `set` operations. If `CreatedAt` isn't expected to return from the API then you could also remove the `set`.

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Cardapio.Models
{
    public class Client
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Ip { get; set; }

        public string Identification { get; set; }

        public string Secrets { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```